# Chrome extension - script loaded event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

Is it possible to get an event (or other way of knowing) when a specific script is loaded into a page?

E.g. I have a page action that should perform action if jQuery is present and have finished loading.

Comment: Can't you wait for `window.onload` and then look for `window.jQuery`?

Comment: @Teepeemm Not that simple, since a content script won't have `window.jQuery` exposed to it from the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up listening for "DOMContentLoaded" and then perform required actions.

Thanks for all input

Comment: This will tell you when the page has finished loading.  But determining whether a specific script is present is a separate and more challenging problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches:

(1) Look to see if a jQuery script was included: in `contentScript.js`:

```
if ( document.querySelector('script[src*="jquery"]') ) {
    // probably has jquery
}
```

(2) Look to see if `jQuery` is defined: in `contentScript.js`:

```
window.addEventListener('jQueryFound',function() {
    // probably has jquery
});
var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
scriptTag.textContent
   = "if ( window.jQuery ) { window.dispatchEvent(new Event('jQueryFound')); }"
document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

(1) will fail if the site author is using bad filenames.  (2) will fail if they’ve redefined `window.jQuery` (or if I messed up my javascript events api, since I’m not the best at javascript).

You could also simplify the above by including jQuery as a content script before you detect if jQuery is included.  ;)

Answer (score -1):

There seems to be a similar stack overflow issue here for the web at large that I think will also apply to your extension: [Trying to fire the onload event on script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230886/trying-to-fire-onload-event-on-script-tag)

It seems that you can set the src and onload elements of a script to get an event when the script loads.

Comment: Does not apply. OP tries to detect a `<script>` tag that is not added by him.