# Javascript: Detecting script load completion

Tags: javascript

I'm dynamically adding script usign:

```
var el = document.createElement("script");
document.getElementsByTagname("head")[0].appendChild(el);
```

It seems neither `script.onload` nor `document.onreadystatechange` could be used to determine the end of loading process. How should I catch dynamic script load completion?

Comment: I think you want something very similar to this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230886/trying-to-fire-onload-event-on-script-tag#16231055

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onload` event needs to be attached before setting the script's `src`, which is what causes the script to start loading.

Example:

```
var el = document.createElement("script");
el.onload = function() {
    // Script is loaded
}
el.src = ...
```

Comment: Thanks. `onload` seem works. Don't know why didn't worked for me before.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something very similar to this: [Trying to fire the onload event on script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230886/trying-to-fire-onload-event-on-script-tag#16231055)

```
$body.append(yourDynamicScriptElement);
yourDynamicScriptElement.onload = function() { //...
yourDynamicScriptElement.src = script;
```