# Fire onload event when script is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have the following code:

```
 $.proxy(function(responseData) {
                    if (responseData.hasOwnProperty('dynamicJavascriptUrl')) {
                         var script = document.createElement('script');
                        script.src = responseData.dynamicJavascriptUrl;
                        script.load = function() {
                            console.log('hello');
                        }
                        $('#credit_card').append($(script));
                    }
```

And what I am trying to do here is to log hello when the script is loaded. 
But it doesnt seem to work.

I have tried this as well:

```
 script.onload = function() {
                            console.log('hello');
                        }
```

But with the same result.

Does anyone have an idea what to do?

Comment: tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16231055/1984039

Comment: It should be `script.onload` for sure, not `script.load` or binding using jQuery `$(script).on('load', handler);`. And ya, set onload event before setting src property. But wait, what is `$.proxy` here? The jQuery one doesn't pass any param to callaback: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

Comment: Try with https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: $.proxy is used here to call exsting functions that do the callback. I did it this way since it has different callbacks depending on what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Code

```
jQuery.loadScript = function (url, callback) {
   jQuery.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'script',
      success: callback,
      async: true
   });
}

$.loadScript('dynamicJavascriptUrl.js', function(){
    console.log('hello');
});
```

Comment: Why not simple and predefined `$.getScript()`? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: jQuery's `$.getScript()` is buggy sometimes... So i use My own implementation,

Comment: undervalued answer ^

You should be able to manage cache too, but its a cool solution

Comment: This solution worked as inteded! Great! Many thanks!