# How to delay variables and functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, document-ready

I get an error in my console, which says **"Firebase is not defined".**

**1. Seems like this "base" code haven't loaded before the other one.**

**EDIT cannot put the script in the header so need to do it this way**

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.src   = "https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

**2. So I need to delay these somehow. How would I achieve that?**

```
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://eloquatest.firebaseio.com/');
myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
var post = snapshot.val();
});

function submitPost(e) {
var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://eloquatest.firebaseio.com/');
var name = $('#field0').val();
myDataRef.push({name: name});
$('#field0').val('');
}
```

**3. I tried to put it within `$( document ).ready(function()` but didn't work.**
Link: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Did you include jquery library as well ?

Comment: use `setTimeout()` to wait a few seconds before fire the function

Comment: What you are looking for is `onload` event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230886/trying-to-fire-onload-event-on-script-tag

Comment: Try loading the library directly into the HTML using `<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>` and then use the `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: how? do you have an example @C0dekid.php

Comment: Did you tried within a `$(window).load(function() { ... });` ? It wait until all the resources are loaded, not only the DOM

Comment: IIRC scripts added dynamically are ´async´ by default. You need to set async to `false`

Comment: try using $( window ).on( 'load', function() { // Your code here ?  } );

Comment: Put firebase load code in your head tag, outside of `$(document).ready();` then put the `$(document).ready();` at bottom page

Comment: @Hbaecklund `setTimeout(function() { console.log("Fire after 1 second."); }, 1000);`

Comment: @Hbaecklund Don't use `setTimeout`. How will you estimate the time needed to wait? It's ridiculous.

Comment: @C0dekid.php added setTimeout of 3 seconds, and it didn't do it

Answer (score 1):

Use `onload` method of `document.createElement()`, this way:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function() {
  // put here code which depends on Firebase to be loaded...
};
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js";
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `onload` event:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
document.head.appendChild(script);

script.onload = function() {
    var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://eloquatest.firebaseio.com/');
    myDataRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var post = snapshot.val();
    });

    function submitPost(e) {
        var myDataRef = new Firebase('https://eloquatest.firebaseio.com/');
        var name = $('#field0').val();
        myDataRef.push({name: name});
        $('#field0').val('');
    }
};
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js";
```

Note that according to this SO thread [ [Trying to fire the onload event on script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230886/trying-to-fire-onload-event-on-script-tag) ] the order of those operations (calling `appendChild`, setting `src` and `onload`) matters. Haven't check that.

Also since you are using jQuery you might want to have a look at `getScript` function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/