# How to select global object inserted dynamically to page with ScalaJS

Tags: scala.js

I tried to insert the Google ReCaptcha script to the page, but I couldn't select the global `grecaptcha`.

```
val script = dom.document.createElement("script").asInstanceOf[HTMLScriptElement]
script.setAttribute("src", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js")
script.setAttribute("async", "true")

script.onload = { (_: Event) =>
  println(Dynamic.global.selectDynamic("grecaptcha")) // --> got undefined
}

dom.document.body.appendChild(script)
```

In the *Console* window, I can get `grecaptcha`:

[image: grecaptcha]

The question is how to select global `grecaptcha` object?

Comment: `window['grecaptacha']` or simply use it as if you defined a global variable, though be careful of the TIME when you use it

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I couldn't access that (this is ScalaJS environment, not usual JS).

Comment: If you cannot access it through `window['grecaptcha']` then it is not a global object. (I had a typo in my previous answer, if you didn't copy-paste you should be fine. All globals are accessible throguh the window object.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer in a vanilla JavaScript environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16231055/1829647), you simply have an ordering problem. The steps should be

1. Append the script to the document
2. Set the `onload` event
3. Set the `src` attribute

```scala
val script = dom.document.createElement("script").asInstanceOf[HTMLScriptElement]
dom.document.body.appendChild(script)
script.onload = { (_: Event) =>
  println(Dynamic.global.selectDynamic("grecaptcha"))
}
script.setAttribute("src", "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js")
script.setAttribute("async", "true")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it gave me the same result.