# How do I add a <script> element after page load?

Tags: dom, vbscript

I am looking for a way to add a script with VBScript dynamically to a page after it is loaded. So far I managed to create a `<script>` element with an attribute that  references to a js file but it won't execute because it is added after the page has loaded.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the script element tells the browser to start downloading it. You then have to wait for the download to complete before the code is available. Add an `onload` event handler to the script tag.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16231055/6550457) for details on a few of the nuances of this.