# Convert Simple Statement from Jquery to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out how to convert below code to Javascript. Is there a conversion tool online for simple conversions?

```
$('head script[async][src*="analytics"]').on('load', function() {
          ga('send', 'event', 'checkout', 'complete');
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to fire onload event on script tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230886/trying-to-fire-onload-event-on-script-tag)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a conversion tool, but there is http://youmightnotneedjquery.com which holds resources for many things one can do without jQuery, compared with the jQuery way.

In your case just replace $() with document.querySelector and .on('load', fn) with .onload = fn i.e:

```
document.querySelector('head script[async][src*="analytics"]').onload = function() {
      ga('send', 'event', 'checkout', 'complete');
    }
```

Let me know if it works!

Comment: try selecting with just document.querySelector('script[src*="analytics"]')

Comment: Same thing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onload' of null".  Problem is that Shopify is loading the script so I can't edit it... and it seems to be taking a few seconds to load.

Comment: I couldn't tell you why but what I see is that when executing querySelector it's not finding the script element with that selector . Try setting a breakpoint with DevTools on that line and check from the console `document.scripts` to see if it's there. Or find another selector to match that script. Good look!