# How to load cdn and access it's objects in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cdn, nuxt.js

I have to load an external javascript file in order to have access to a certain object.

Normally the code is very simple:

```
<script src='https://example.com/example.js'></script>

<script>

  var instance = new ExampleObj.start({ container: 'element-id' });

</script>

<div id='element-id'></div>
```

How do I accomplish this in a `.vue` file?

***This did not work*:**

```
export default {
  ...
  mounted() {
    const script = document.createElement('script')

    script.setAttribute('src', 'https://example.com/example.js')

    const start = document.createElement('script')

    start.text = `var instance = new ExampleObj.start({ container: 'element-id' });`

    document.body.appendChild(script)
    document.body.appendChild(start)
  }
  ...
}
```

The ^ above examples gives error: `ExampleObj not defined`, however if I try to access `ExampleObj` it shows up on the developer console with the `start` method working.

Comment: Sounds like timing: the script tags get attached, but it takes some time for them to load. You could try using `onload` on them to indicate readiness.

Comment: If you are indeed using nuxt, then use external resources noted in the docs https://nuxtjs.org/faq/ though think about grabbing the lib and having it local instead.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Add your CDN script in your index.html above vue.js scripts. I would put it right before head ending tag:

`<script src='https://example.com/example.js'></script>
</head>`

2. If you use webpack - add to [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) so you can import it in your vue component.
3. If you don't use webpack - access the JS object using window.ExampleObject in your mounted () function.

Answer (score -1):

you should wait for the script to be loaded:

```
const script = document.createElement('script')

const start = document.createElement('script')

start.text = `console.log('jquery object', $('#app').text())`

script.onload = () => {
    document.body.appendChild(start)
}

script.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js')

document.body.appendChild(script)
```

> You should set the src attribute after the onload event

From this question: [Trying to fire the onload event on script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230886/trying-to-fire-the-onload-event-on-script-tag)

Here is a working jsFiddle I made: https://jsfiddle.net/jovmypnx/1/