# Waiting Until Javascript Loads With A Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am building a solution in which multiple Javascript libraries are dynamically loaded onto the screen at different points in time based on the user's interaction. After the libraries are loaded, the scripts in the library are executed.

For example:

```
    let script1 = '<script class="'+script_class+'" id="' + script_id + '" type="text/javascript" src="' + some_script_url +'"></script>';
    
     $("head").append(script1);

let script2 = '<script class="'+script_class+'" id="' + script_id + '" type="text/javascript" src="' + some_script_url +'"></script>';
    
     $("head").append(script2);

let script3 = '<script class="'+script_class+'" id="' + script_id + '" type="text/javascript" src="' + some_script_url +'"></script>';
    
     $("head").append(script3);
```

And then a function will execute a function inside the script:

```
function doSomething() {
      scriptFunction();
}

doSomething();
```

The problem is sometimes the script will not fully be loaded before the function tries execute. This causes error likes "scriptFunction not found". How can I wait for each libraries to load before executing the scripting? Can this be done with promises?

Comment: Scripts loaded as you're loading them fire a "load" event when loading is complete, so you can wait for that.

Comment: @Pointy The reason why I am looking for a promise route is because I do a Promise.all() where I can wait for all the scripts.

Comment: Sure, well you can wrap the `<script>` imports with a function that returns a Promise that is resolved within a "load" handler. Then any call to a function from within a particular script can use that Promise and put the code in a `.then()` handler.

Comment: See the answer on how to load scripts in order in this topic [Trying to fire the onload event on script tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76680818/17045797)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function that returns a promise that resolves when a script has loaded:

```js
function loadScript(src) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        script.setAttribute("async", "");
        script.onload = resolve;
        script.setAttribute("src", src);
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    });
}

const urls = [
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js",
    "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.1/luxon.min.js"
];

Promise.all(urls.map(loadScript)).then(ready);

function ready() {
    console.log("all loaded");
    console.log($.fn.jquery);
    console.log(luxon.DateTime.now().toString());
}
```