# Cordova / Phonegap ios load script not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

I am building an with cordova.js library [version 3.4.1] and I would also like to debug it as web page directly using the web browser.

There are some issues in iOS emulator when loading dynamically the external cordova.js library [I have 2 version specific for android and iOS]

I have this piece of code in place to deal with this:

```
//check if mobile or local browser:
var isMobile = true;
if (document.URL.indexOf("local") > 0) {
    isMobile = false;
}

var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();

function onDeviceReady () {
    deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
}
if (isMobile) {
    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
        $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
        jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
        var useragent = navigator.userAgent;

        var loadScript = function (url) {
            url = url.replace(/\//, '\\/');
            document.write('<script charset="utf-8" src="' + url + ' "><\/script>');
        };

        if (/Android/i.test(useragent)) {
            $.getScript('js/lib/cordova_android.js', function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                document.addEventListener("deviceReady", onDeviceReady, false);
            });
        } else {
            loadScript('js/lib/cordova_ios.js');
            setTimeout(function () {
                document.addEventListener("deviceReady", onDeviceReady, false);
            }, 500);
        }
    });
} else {
    jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
    onDeviceReady();
}
```

So when the page is requested with localhost... then the isMobile is set to false. 
Is there a reason why iOS [6.1] does not load the external script like Android did [with jQuery getscript ] instead than the horrible hack ? I tried to debug and it seems that iOS is reporting status error 400 when requesting the script.

Followed the logic used in this other SO question:
[Issue with dynamically loaded phonegap.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783144/issue-with-dynamically-loaded-phonegap-js)

**UPDATE:**

Following the suggestion of the accepted answer, I rewrote the whole  function and now it is working well both in iOS / ANDROID and local browser:

```
var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();

(function () {
    //check if mobile or local browser:
    var isMobile = true;
    var useragent = navigator.userAgent;

    var cordova_js = 'cordova_';
    if (/Android/i.test(useragent)) {
        cordova_js += 'android.js'
    } else if ((/iPhone/i.test(useragent)) || (/iPad/i.test(useragent))) {
        cordova_js += 'ios.js'
    } else {
        // local browser testing
        isMobile = false;
        jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
        onDeviceReady();
    }

    if (isMobile) {
        $(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
            $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
            jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();

            var url = document.URL;
            url = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/"));
            $.getScript(url + '/js/lib/' + cordova_js, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                document.addEventListener("deviceReady", onDeviceReady, false);
            });
        });
    }

    function onDeviceReady () {
        deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your isMobile check is prone to break. Think of a remote URL like this:

```
http://www.somesite.com/local/foo/bar
```

And probably the "local" URL in iOS looks different. Try logging the `document.URL` in iOS to check, or maybe show it in an alert if console is not an option.

Comment: Thx, that is a good hint. I revised my original question above adding the full new code that can be useful for someone.