# JavaScript - How to load external script NON-asynchronously?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for code that allows me to use JavaScript to load another JavaScript file NON-asynchronously. I tried this:

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
script.setAttribute("src", "jquery.min.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);

$("div.whatever").css("color","red");
```

But that doesn't work. It inserts the script node okay, but it continues to run the rest of the script before jQuery loads. This ends up failing because the jQuery code tries to run when `$` isn't defined by jQuery yet.

Is there a way to load that script non-async using native JS?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3248384/document-createelementscript-synchronously

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically loading JavaScript synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879509/dynamically-loading-javascript-synchronously)

Comment: ^-- Possibly duplicated comments ^^

Comment: Yeah go ahead and delete/close it. Didn't see the duplicates when I searched for some reason. Could only find stuff about async loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the `<script>` nodes `.onload` event handler, to continue/execute any code which should be executed after the script was loaded, like

```
script.onload = function() {
    // continune here
};
```

or you can try to set the `async` flag to `false`

```
script.setAttribute("async", false);
```

While the former solution virtually works in any browser available, the latter one might be not supported by old'ish browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading synchronously, a slightly better idea might be to use `onload`:

```
script.onload = function() {
  // $ is defined now
};

// append it only now to make sure it does not load before setting onload
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```