# Uncaught ReferenceError when Loading a Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a simple Bookmarklet that will load some external Javascript into a page, the goal is to add a markdown editor like Stackoverflow has to another site.  I have it working but it requires me to click my Bookmarklet button 2 times instead of 1 time.

The first click gives this error...

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Markdown is not defined init.js:46
```

Line 46 is this...

```
var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
```

Now after clicking my Bookmarklet for the 2nd time then everything runs perfectly but always the first click will give that error and do nothing.

Here is the code for the Bookmarklet file, please help me to fix, my Javascript skills are not too great.

Load external JS and CSS files

```
function loadScripts(scriptURL) {
    var scriptElem = document.createElement('SCRIPT');
    scriptElem.setAttribute('language', 'JavaScript');
    scriptElem.setAttribute('src', scriptURL);
    void(document.body.appendChild(scriptElem));
}

// Load these 3 Javascript files into the page
// jQuery is already loaded into the page being used so no need to load it
loadScripts('http://codedevelopr.com/labs/javascript/forrst/Markdown.Converter.js');
loadScripts('http://codedevelopr.com/labs/javascript/forrst/Markdown.Sanitizer.js');
loadScripts('http://codedevelopr.com/labs/javascript/forrst/Markdown.Editor.js');

// Load the CSS file into the Page
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
$(document.createElement('link')).attr({
    type: 'text/css',
    href: 'http://codedevelopr.com/labs/javascript/forrst/demo.css',
    rel: 'stylesheet'
}).appendTo(head);
```

After the files are loaded then we run this...

```
// Find and replace the curent textarea with the HTML we
// need for our markdown editor to work 
$(document).ready(function () {
    var htmlToReplace = ' \
  <div class="wmd-panel"> \
    <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div> \
      <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input" name="description"></textarea> \
  </div> \
  <div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview"></div>';

    $("#description").replaceWith(htmlToReplace);

    //Run the Markdown editor!
    var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();

    var editor1 = new Markdown.Editor(converter1);
    editor1.run();

});
```

Comment: The 3 external scripts are appended at runtime but loaded asynchronously, you'll need to load them synchronously or set a callback to start the markdown after the scripts are loaded. You could try adapting your `loadScripts` function to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2880147/1331430).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté is right. To put it in laymans terms, the browser doesn't wait for each script to be loaded before proceeding in the code. all 3 scripts get loaded simultaneously and the rest of your script runs before the other 3 scripts finish loading.

Comment: @Kranklin Yes that's better explained. `=]` With jQuery you could use `$.getScript` and set a callback to still load it async and get it to work, but without jQuery I guess you'll have to load them synchronously which may hang your browser.

Comment: Oh you're already using jQuery. This should be easy to fix then. One last question though, all of the code above is in a single bookmarklet right?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: The `$.getScript` looks like a possible good solution but since I would need all 3 files loaded before running my callback function, would I just supply a callback function to one of them?

Comment: @jasondavis: Sounds like you want `$.when` and `.then`. That will allow you to defer the markdown code appropriately.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: Yes jQuery is already loaded in the page I am viewing/appending to and yes it's a single JS file minus the 3 JS files that are loaded into it

Comment: Yes jason, you can wrap all 3 `$.getScript` calls inside a [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) (and `then`) as @pimvdb suggested. =]

Comment: @Fabrício Matté: What I actually meant is wrapping the `$.getScript`s in `$.when` and passing the callback to `.then` :)

Comment: Oh I see, that should work nicely. =] Post some example so I can +1 it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script files are not loaded yet at the time you're using markdown. You've merely sent the requests. You have to wait until the response is received and parsed.

I've cleaned your code up a bit as well as you're using jQuery:

```
var urls = [
  'http://codedevelopr.com/labs/javascript/forrst/Markdown.Converter.js',
  'http://codedevelopr.com/labs/javascript/forrst/Markdown.Sanitizer.js',
  'http://codedevelopr.com/labs/javascript/forrst/Markdown.Editor.js'
];

// map urls to getScript calls, and pass them to $.when
$.when.apply($, $.map(urls, $.getScript)).then(function() {
  // use markdown here
});

$("<link>", {
  href: 'http://codedevelopr.com/labs/javascript/forrst/demo.css',
  rel: 'stylesheet'
}).appendTo("head");
```

Comment: @Fabrício Matté: It's an interesting function to remember. It can come in very handy at times.

Comment: Yes, I hardly ever make use of the JS [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) function as well, favoriting the question for future reference.

Comment: This is very clean, thanks to you and @FabrícioMatté for the help =)

Comment: 1 issue maybe you can help.  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined`

Comment: @jasondavis: Perhaps an older jQuery version?

Comment: ahh you are right it looks like the page uses v1.4 and current is 1.7.2 maybe I will have to load in my own jquery