# IE9 - SCRIPT5009: "jQuery" is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cross-browser

the following code runs into the error *SCRIPT5009: "jQuery" is undefined* in IE9 (maybe also in older IE versions):

```
var $tx;
if (window.jQuery) {
    $tx = jQuery;
    if( jQuery().jquery.replace(".", "") < 17.1 ) {
        addjQuery();
    }   
} else {
    addjQuery();
}
function addjQuery() {
    document.write('<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript">$tx = jQuery.noConflict();<\/script>');
}
document.write('<script src="workingScript.js"><\/script>');
```

I solved it! It's working fine this way:

```
var $tx;
if (window.jQuery) {
    $tx = jQuery;
    if( jQuery().jquery.replace(".", "") < 17.1 ) {
        addjQuery();
    }   
} else {
    addjQuery();
}
function addjQuery() {
    loadScript("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js", function(){
        $tx = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    });
}
document.write('<script src="workingScript.js"><\/script>');

function loadScript(url, callback){

    var script = document.createElement("script")
    script.type = "text/javascript";

    if (script.readyState){  //IE
        script.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (script.readyState == "loaded" ||
                    script.readyState == "complete"){
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        script.onload = function(){
            callback();
        };
    }
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

workingScript.js:

```
(function ($) {
    // some code here
})($tx);
```

The error occours here *"$tx = jQuery.noConflict();"* if `addjQuery` function is called. If the website already uses the current jQuery version, erverythings works fine.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: First make sure that addjQuery is adding the script.

Comment: Checking again with window.jQuery? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your script loads other scripts during its execution, they won't execute synchronously but rather asynchronously. When `$tx = jQuery.noConflict();` executes there is no guarantee the jQuery loaded.

If you need to do it synchronously [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879509/dynamically-loading-javascript-synchronously) , or better yet use something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) that handles this for you. (It also allows that sort of fallback).

Comment: You're very welcome, if my answer was useful to you please consider up-voting it. If it solved your problem please consider accepting it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum note you need some basic reputation to upvote. I have that reputation ;-)

Comment: createXMLHttpObject isn't really a method, it's just a name he used in that answer to illustrate his point. I like the second answer better because it is not synchronous but callback based though.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum you mean Alan Joseph's answer?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thank you so much, the callback based approach is perfect. I added my solution above.