# How to dynamically append JS/CSS files in order

Tags: javascript

So, I have to load these in the main page

```
jQuery.js
jQueryMobile.css
jQueryMobile.js
mainScript.js
```

But if the user enters from anywhere else I need to load them dynamically. so I have

scriptCheck.js

```
if scripts not present
    //create array of elements containing above files
    scriptsArray.forEach do |script|
        head.append(script)
    end forEach
end if
```

My question is, is there a way to make the loading a synchronous operation, that waits for each script to load and be interpreted before loading the next one?

Comment: Where are the original scripts printed? Seems like a job for the server side...

Comment: Yes. You would set the onload handler of each script element to be the function that loads the next script.

Comment: Printed? they are loaded on the front-end, the client machine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically loading JavaScript synchronously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879509/dynamically-loading-javascript-synchronously)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the onload handler of each script element to be a function that loads the next script:

```
var counter = 0
scriptpaths = [...]
function loadnextscript(){
    var el = document.createElement("script");

    el.onload = loadnextscript;
    el.src = scriptpaths[counter];

    document.head.appendChild(el);

    counter++;
}
```

You can then invoke this using:

```
if (scriptsnotpresent) {
    loadnextscript();
}
```

Comment: Should be `el.onload = loadnextscript` instead of `el.onload = loadnextscript()`, right?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2880147/1391624

It uses createXMLHTTPObject() to open and send a synchronous request.

Comment: If you feel a question is adequately answered somewhere else, please mark it as a duplicate, or at the very least actually explain in the body of your answer how the problem would be solved.

Comment: In this case are you suggesting I should have included more of the linked solution in my answer?

Comment: If the answer you are linking to solves this problem as is, without any changes or elaboration needed, then you should mark this question as a duplicate of that one. You can do this yourself using close votes once you have sufficient reputation, but in the meantime you can flag the question as a duplicate. If the linked answer demonstrates an approach that can be repurposed to solve this problem, please reproduce the relevant parts and elaborate.

Comment: I see the flag link for my own answer, but not for any of the other answers or the question. Perhaps I need a higher reputation to flag as well?

Comment: Perhaps. Let me look into this. Edit: yes, according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges, you will need 15 reputation to flag. Also, note that you should flag the *question* as a duplicate, not an answer.

Comment: Of course, I was just mentioning the inability to flag other answers to make it clear what I see on my screen. The ability to flag my own answer is a bit odd.  
**Edit:** It also seems buggy. I see two radio buttons, one for moderator attention, the other is an indented option for 'other'. Moderator attention is selected by default and selecting 'other' keeps the moderator option selected.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see what you're seeing. This would be a discussion more suited to Meta though, where the site itself (bugs, requests, inquiries) is discussed. You can access that at 5 reputation.